# Help with Trigger Handler SOQL

Tags: apex, trigger, soql

Below is the code for my TriggerHandler: My query is not returning a UserId. UI get an error

> List has no rows for assignment to SObject:
>   Class.OpportunityTriggerHandler.HandleMethod: line 30, column 1

```
public class OpportunityTriggerHandler
 {
    Public static void HandleMethod(List<Opportunity> oppList)
    {
        List<Case> casList = new List<Case>();
        List<Task> taskList = new List<Task>();
        List<User> userList = new List<User>();

        for(Opportunity opp: oppList)
        {
            Contact con = [Select Id,Name from Contact where Id =: opp.Contact__c];

            if(opp.StageName == 'Signed LOI')
            {
                // Inserting Case        
                Case c = new Case();
                c.Origin = 'Phone';
                c.Support_Group__c = 'Transitions';
                c.Subject = 'World Class Onboarding for : '+con.Name;
                c.Description = 'Please attend to the activities assigned to this World Class Onboarding Case';
                c.Priority = 'Medium';
                c.Status = 'New';
                c.ContactId = con.Id;
                casList.add(c);
                // Invoking Assignment Rules        

                AssignmentRule AR = new AssignmentRule();
                AR = [Select Id from AssignmentRule where SobjectType = 'Case' and Active = true limit 1];
                Database.DMLOptions dmlopts = new Database.DMLOptions();
                dmlopts.assignmentRuleHeader.assignmentRuleId = AR.Id;
                c.setOptions(dmlopts);
                insert casList;    

                 // Inserting Task              
                Case cas = [Select Id,ContactId,OwnerId from Case where ContactId =: opp.Contact__c AND Status != 'Closed' limit 1];
                User usr = [Select Id, Email from User where Email =: opp.Consultant_Contact__r.Unique_Email__c];
                System.debug('Selected Case details are:'+cas);
                Task t = new Task();
                t.OwnerId = usr.Id;
                t.Subject = 'LOI Signed and Released';
                t.Priority = 'Medium';
                t.WhatId = cas.Id;
                t.WhoId = cas.ContactId;
                t.ActivityDate = System.TODAY()+1;
                taskList.add(t);
                System.debug('Task Details are: '+taskList);
                insert taskList;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code has some fundamental issues.

You are executing SOQL query inside `for` loop, as well as performing DML like inserting `Case` and `Task`.

So, you have to follow [Apex Code best practices](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Apex_Code_Best_Practices) to work on those issues.

> `List has no rows for assignment to SObject` error occurs when you are trying to return a specific Object (e.g. User) from SOQL query and SOQL is unable to return any records.

So, better to change the code to return a `List` and if the size is greater than  zero, then retrieve the User object.

```
List<User> lstUser = [Select Id,Email from User where Email =: opp.Onboarding_Consultant_Email__c];
if(lstUser.size()>0)
{   
    User usr = lstUser[0];
}
```

**Update based on comments**

Here is an approach to collect ContactIds in `for` loop and perform SOQL outside of `for` loop.

```
Set<Id> contactIds = new Set<Id>();
for(Opportunity opp: oppList)
{
    contactIds.add(opp.Contact__c);
}
List<Contact> con = [Select Id,Name from Contact where Id IN:contactIds];
```

Comment: @shantanu Thank you so much I am a complete beginner and just getting to know the rules. Thank you for sharing the information. I have a quick question how will I be able to write a query outside for loop when I am trying to associate it with the opportunity record that is in play.                                                     For eg: How can I write this code below outside of the for loop. Please advise.                                                                                                          
       Contact con = [Select Id,Name from Contact where Id =: opp.Contact__c];

Comment: I have tried your approach to place to SOQL Query outside the for loop and it gives me an error saying "The variable does not exists"

Comment: modify your entire approach and create a new question, I know it will be bit learning for you to bulkify the code